# Looping inside .append jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I've 2 array of elements coming from PHP. I've stored the elements in 2 variable in javascript
then looped 1 variable to create a table to show the element

I want to create  element in append and loop another array to bind or dynamically show other elements in

here is my code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#courier_id").change(function (){
        var c_id =  $(this).val();
        var totalCOD    =   0;
        $('#data').empty();
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "json",
          data: {
              'delivery_courier' : c_id
          },
          url: "<?=base_url()?>Admin/get_deliverd_consignmnet",
          success: function(data) {
              var status    =   data.status;
              var consignment   =   data.consignment;      
          if(consignment.length > 0){
              $("#table").css({"display":"block"});
              $("#nodata").css({"display":"none"});

              $.each(consignment, function(idx, obj) {


                  $("#data").append("<tr><td><input value="+obj.c_id+" total="+obj.cod+" type=checkbox style='width: 24px;height: 23px;'/>"+"</td><td>"+obj.c_id+"</td><td>"+obj.consignee_name+"</td><td>"+obj.consignee_address+"</td><td>"+obj.cod+"</td><td>"+obj.code+" - "+obj.description+"</td><td><select>'2nd loop start here'<option></option>'2nd loop end here'</select></td></tr>");

              });
              $("#data").append("<tr><td colspan='4'><b><center>Total</center></b></td><td id='field_results'></td><td></td><td></td></tr>");

              $("input:checkbox").click(function() {
                var output=0;
                $("input:checked").each(function() {
                  output += Number($(this).attr('total'));
                });
                $("#field_results").html(output);
              });
          }
          else{
              $("#table").css({"display":"none"});
              $("#nodata").css({"display":"block"});
          }
          }
        });
    });
});
```

1st var looped is consignment
2nd var that i want to loop is status

[image: variable table from JavaScript]

Comment: Instead of looping and constructing the `<tr><td>` in JS, you can construct that in the PHP code as a string and directly append it to the desired table body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the loop for the options first and them save them in a string variable:

```
var options = "";
$.each(status, function () {
    options += "<option>"+status.attribute+"</option>"
})
```

Then, concat this string to your append:

```
$("#data").append("<tr><td><input value="+obj.c_id+" total="+obj.cod+" type=checkbox style='width: 24px;height: 23px;'/>"+"</td><td>"+obj.c_id+"</td><td>"+obj.consignee_name+"</td><td>"+obj.consignee_address+"</td><td>"+obj.cod+"</td><td>"+obj.code+" - "+obj.description+"</td><td><select>"+options+"</select></td></tr>");
```

There's lots of ways to do it, but I think this one is simplier for you because it is aligned with your line of thought.

Comment: Good answer, i used the same code and it worked like a charm